# Declaration with interface overhead

Tags: c#, .net, performance

If I declare and use a private variable like

> ICollection v = new List()

does it lead to any kind of usage overhead in comparison to

> List v = new List()

Variable is not being casted anywhere in the code and not exposed to external entities via field/property/etc.

Comment: Well, in first example you couldn't use `v[index]`.

Comment: Instead of trying to learn millions of rules for writing the most performant code, I'd instead recommend you write clear, readable code that does the job you need. Also, set performance *goals*. Then, *measure* the code's performance. Only if it doesn't meet the goals should you consider re-writing it - but make sure you've identified *where* the bottleneck is. I'd be 100% certain that the choice of variable type won't be the difference between your code performing adequately or not (it may make the difference between your code being correct or incorrect, or clean vs ugly, however)